# SQL - How to query next row data as new column

Tags: sql

I want to write a sql statement which can achieve the target below

Say i have a table as below

| CLASS | ID | NAME | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST1 | A1 | ALI | 12 |
| ST1 | B1 | MING | 13 |
| ST1 | C1 | ABU | 12 |

and i want to write a sql query which able to extract the data as below

| CLASS | ID | NAME | AGE | ID | NAME | AGE | ID | NAME | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ST1 | A1 | ALI | 12 | B1 | MING | 13 | C1 | ABU | 12 |

Comment: What you want is called a "PIVOT", many examples exist for you to research. **BUT** you need to know which database you use because some versions Oracle has pivot features that don't exist in some version of MySQL, and then there is Postgres and a myriad of other dbms's to consider. **SQL** is near useless as a tag, instead choose a tag that represents your dbms. - and it may be necessary to know the version of that dbms as well (include in question).

Comment: Regarding the tag "SQL" if you hover over that tag please read its description: "*Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with this, the next, and the "second-next" row, you could take advantage of the fact that the data would be ordered by `id` - and probably partitioned by `class` (you'd start anew if the `class` changes).

The OLAP / analytic function *LAG()* is what will help you here.

And - don't use more than one occurrence of the same column name in a report - hence the `n1_` and `n2_` prefixes for next-by-one and next-by-two.

Next, you will have to filter out those rows that don't have all columns of the report populated. Hence, the query with the `LAG()` function in a sub select - which I call `pivot_using_lag` - and finally select from that named sub select filtering by the next-by-two row's `id` not being NULL - you can't put OLAP functions into a WHERE condition.

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(CLASS,ID,NAME,AGE) AS (
          SELECT 'ST1','A1','ALI' ,12
UNION ALL SELECT 'ST1','B1','MING',13
UNION ALL SELECT 'ST1','C1','ABU' ,12
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
pivot_using_lag AS (
  SELECT 
    class
  , id
  , name
  , age
  , LEAD(id  ) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n1_id 
  , LEAD(name) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n1_name
  , LEAD(age ) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n1_age
  , LEAD(id  ,2) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n2_id 
  , LEAD(name,2) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n2_name
  , LEAD(age ,2) OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY id) AS n2_age
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  *
FROM pivot_using_lag
WHERE n2_id IS NOT NULL
;
-- out  class | id | name | age | n1_id | n1_name | n1_age | n2_id | n2_name | n2_age 
-- out -------+----+------+-----+-------+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------
-- out  ST1   | A1 | ALI  |  12 | B1    | MING    |     13 | C1    | ABU     |     12
```